# How do I access an object value from a cached JSON API in Redis cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, caching, redis

In my Rails app, I have gotten to the stage where I stored the nested API JSON objects as the value of my Redis key eg. "A". The whole object is accessed by calling a GET of "A". However, what would I need to do if I want to change of the value of a certain name of the object? Since I stored the whole JSON object as Redis value, would I need to create a new model and replicate the same values within the model and alter through a for instance Postgres? Or is there a way to target a specific value in the JSON object that is stored as value of key "A" in Redis? If so, how would I create the routes to allow a front end developer to update the cache outside of the rails app?

Answer (score 1):

Redis does not natively support modifying JSON documents within its values; there are some [experimental plugins](https://matt.sh/redis-json) for doing so, but most likely, you will need to deserialize the current value (`doc = redis.get('A')`), modify it (`doc['name'] = 'foo'`), and then reserialize and store it back into Redis (`redis.set('A', JSON.encode(doc))`).

However, if you're interested in working with JSON documents like this at scale, or perhaps querying on your JSON documents' values within your database, I'd strongly suggest you use either a NoSQL JSON document store (e.g. MongoDB), or take advantage of Postgres' new-ish native JSON support.

Also, your comments about "allowing a front-end dev to update the cache outside of the Rails stack" are a little worrying; if you're exposing write access to your database (be it Redis, Mongo, or Postgres) directly to the front-end, you're potentially exposing yourself to a host of security issues. If you want that ability, and you want to modify JSON documents like you propose, you might find yourself best off by using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) -- it's designed for direct client-side access, uses JSON natively, and has a lot of support and tooling available.

Comment: Mostly accurate - you can always use Lua to avoid at least some of the pains. In addition, there has been some recent development in that area - check my answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your input Robert. If I may ask, what are the benefits for choosing either the deserializing method or the working with a database (MongoDB/PG)?

Comment: Deserializing and reserializing locally is going to require you to download and then upload the full JSON body from and to the server, which adds bandwidth and network costs. So if you're doing a lot of it, that's not a good option. @ItamarHaber has good points on how you can still use Redis to do what you want, though.

Comment: When  you write  "you're potentially exposing yourself to a host of security issues. " What kind of security issues are you talking about mainly?

Comment: You risk allowing malicious users to manipulate your database beyond what you allow. For example, if your Redis server is storing post data, and you expose the connection via Javascript with static credentials, a user could execute Javascript to alter posts which aren't their own. You would need to pass down per-user, per-session credentials (i.e., a token) to the browser, and use some means to ensure that token only allows the user to modify their own documents. It's often easier to move such logic into your API.

Answer (score 0):

> Redis does not natively support modifying JSON documents within its values;

said correctly @Robert Nubel, but you do have two viable alternatives for achieving that:

1. Server-side Lua scripts - Redis' Lua sandbox is shipped with the [`cjson`](https://redis.io/commands/eval#cjson) library. You can use it to extract/update any element from an embedded serialized JSON string, without the network penality. You can find a bunch of scripts that do that at https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/rejson/tree/master/benchmarks/lua
2. Redis Modules - the above-referred scripts are a (non-essential) part of a newly-developed Redis module that provides a native JSON data type for Redis. The module is still in preview mode, but I believe that it will be made GA and added with features in the near future (disclosure - author here ;)). You can find ReJSON, the JSON data type for Redis at https://github.com/redislabsmodules/rejson and be sure to check the [comparative results vs. the Lua approach](https://redislabsmodules.github.io/rejson/performance/#comparison-vs-server-side-lua-scripting)